# Cannot read property 'search' of undefined - webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

A bit of context: I am trying to use `static-site-generator-webpack-plugin` to create a server-side static website in react.

Could someone possibly help me out please with the following error:

```
ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined
    at Object.eval (webpack:///(webpack)-dev-server/client?:31:28)
    at eval (webpack:///(webpack)-dev-server/client?:248:30)
    at Object../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:8081 (evalmachine.<anonymous>:276:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (evalmachine.<anonymous>:30:30)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_(webpack)-dev-server/client?:1:1)
    at Object.0 (evalmachine.<anonymous>:377:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (evalmachine.<anonymous>:30:30)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:79:18
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:82:10
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (evalmachine.<anonymous>:3:20)
```

The command I am using to start the server is `webpack-dev-server --mode development`

The versions are:

```
static-site-generator-webpack-plugin: ^3.4.1
webpack-cli: ^2.1.3
webpack: ^4.8.1,
webpack-dev-server: ^3.1.4
node: 8.11.1
```

My webpack looks like this:

```
/*global require, module*/
const path = require("path")
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")
const StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin = require('static-site-generator-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/entry.js",
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve("dist"),
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("dist/styles/main.css"),
        new StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin({
            paths: [
                '/'
            ],
            globals: {
                window: {}
            }
        })
    ]
}
```

And finally the entry file looks like this:

```
module.exports = function render(locals) {
    return '<html>Hello World</html>'
}
```

I am grateful for any feedback regarding the issue I am having. This is the first time I am using this plugin.

Links:

- [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/markdalgleish/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin/issues/131)
- [static-site-generator-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/markdalgleish/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin)

Comment: The plugin wasn't updated in a long time. Have you tried with an older webpack version? It might just not work with 4

Comment: @lukas-reineke thank you for your help! Got it working with webpack 2.3.3 and webpack-dev-server 1.16.4! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lukas-reineke mentioned in the above comment:

> The plugin wasn't updated in a long time. Have you tried with an older webpack version? It might just not work with 4.

I got it working with webpack `2.3.3` and webpack-dev-server `1.16.4`

Also for anyone interested in a boilerplate, I found [react isomorphic static site generator boilerplate](https://github.com/VaclavSynacek/react-isomorphic-static-site-generator-boilerplate) which uses this plugin.